# Place a "root" node in an undirected graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to model computer networks in Python using Networkx with the built-in Barabasi-Albert graph generator. My understanding is that this better represents a real network.

I want to randomly select a node as a entry/exist point for an attacker and visualize it with matplotlib. However, this "random" node can be place pretty much anywhere in the layout (I'm currently using the spring layout). This looks a little weird sometimes as the selected node could be right in the middle of the visualization, as if the entry/exit node is from within the network vs the network edge.

While a case could be made that this could represent insider threats, that's not something I would like to show at this time.

Is there an easy way I can position the node so that it's on the "exterior" of the graph? Or perhaps "pick" one of the nodes on the "exterior" as this entry/exit?

Comment: one comment - whether the BA networks are better representations of real networks depends on what those networks are.

Comment: Are you going to do multiple visualizations with the same network?   An approach would be to choose a node and then specify its position before using the spring layout to choose the other node positions.

Comment: @Joel, any other representations you're aware of which you would suggest?